# Actionscript 3: Simple Button

Tags: actionscript-3, button, actionscript, frame, layer

I am working on a project in which a button is clicked, and the frame jumps and stops at a certain area. The button I have is called cancelmenu_btn. It is spread over 1 keyframe (over 5 frames) on an actions layer. The coding for the back button is:

```
menuback_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menubackClick);
function menubackClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (2);
    }
```

Yet, the back button only works on one of the frames - frame 3. I have a link to my project:

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=9AB08B59DCCDF9C6&resid=9AB08B59DCCDF9C6%21110&authkey=ALkJwkJaKg7ypI0

What am I doing wrong with the menuback_btn?

Comment: The coding is on the second frame, and the button is on the second, third, fourth, and fifth frame. This is all inside a movieclip.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you have to check if you want the button active. First, make sure your code is on the first frame because it does not become active until that frame hits.

Second, make sure your button is also on the first frame, but then it will associate your btn.addEventListener(Function) correctly.

Comment: The coding is on the second frame, and the button is on the second, third, fourth, and fifth frame. This is all inside a movieclip.

Comment: Do you want the button to jump to frame 2 within the movieclip or on the main timeline?

Comment: Within the movieclip. I went back and renamed every button and put coding for every frame, which wasn't very efficient, but effective.

Comment: Another question -- how would you go about saying something like: if (frame==1) locationname.text = "Home" properly?

Comment: if (btn.currentFrame == 1) { txtName.text = "Home" } I hope that's what you were looking for.